# Rectified X2 circuit gives 2 voltages depending on how the powerplug is connected to the wall (EU)

Tags: power-supply, ac, rectifier, voltage-measurement

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fT63Pt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm trying to control a mosfet directly from a phase shifted 50Hz sine wave. But when I was trying to understand the voltage drop with X2 capacitors something weird happend.

Depending on how I plug the power plug in the wall the voltage measured at the arrows changes. It measures 3.5VDC or 8.5 ~ 9 VDC when the power plug is turned 180 degrees.

This phenomenon also happens when the second (or first) X2 capacitor is removed.

**Can someone explain why this is happening?**

Edit: control tests:

- used 10 different x2 capacitors
- used 4 different full bridge rectifiers which each gave the full 331VDC output when all X2 capacitors were removed

Edit: Ground connection:

- the ground is connected to the full bridge rectifier.

Comment: Do you have something else hooked up to your contraption? Are all diodes intact in your bridge?

Comment: Is your DC ground connected to mains earth or is it fully isolated. Put all the info into your question (and not sprinkled through the comments).